# Which one is correct and natural: "pay a fee" or "pay for a fee"?

Tags: prepositions

Would you tell me which one is correct and natural *pay a fee* or *pay for a fee*? For example:

> To be able to watch the boxing match online, you have to **pay a fee** of 10 dollars.
>
> To be able to watch the boxing match online, you have to **pay for a fee** of 10 dollars.

I thought that you use *pay for* for things you buy, not fees. But, I have heard people use *pay for* when talking about paying fees. Is it a standard usage?

Answer (score 2):

The first.

The second whilst grammatically correct, is certainly not what you intended semantically.

It would mean that you were paying to get a fee, which is unlikely to make any sense.